# Get absolute path of image saved by paperclip in Serializer of rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am saving images using Paperclip,
while writing an API I need to get absolute path of image instead of relative path.

I have tried dozen of ways but they didn't worked, 
Actually `URI.join` or `Request.host` are not working in serializer.
in serialzier I have a method to get URL

```
def picture
   object.picture.url(:medium)
end
```

How to get absolute path in serilaizer???

Comment: Your question would be easier to answer if you provided more information about your case. Mostly some code would be helpful, i.e. relevant portions of the model and the serializer.

Comment: In the meantime: Paperclip provides a method `#path` on attachments. Try that one. And if it does solve your case, let us know!

Comment: Then you are probably using a cloud based paperclip backend, right?

Comment: @Raffael my project is deployed on Cloud66 but I 'm using paperclip in similar way.
difference is that now I need to get full path in serializer
Didn't get you about "cloud based paperclip backend"???

Comment: Does this occur in production or on your development machine? Are you sure that the paperclip attachment is even available on the local filesystem?

Comment: Paperclip can be used with local file storage or a cloud. I assume that you are using a cloud. (Maybe your hoster imposes that on you.) Please read [the section about storage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#storage) in Paperclip's readme.

Comment: on local as well on cloud it give relative path

Comment: From what little information you yielded so far I just cannot seem to understand what exactly your problem is. Hopefully someone else will be able to help you.